# Simplifying my function

Tags: r, function, loops, statistics

I have the following code:

```
    z7 <- function(data, k, e){
  require(zoo)
  df = data
  r = df$ROA
  t = df$t
  EA = df$EA
  k = k
  e = e

  #Estimate rolling linear models
  models = rollapply(df, width = k, FUN = function(z) 
    coef(lm(r~t, data = as.data.frame(z))), by.column = FALSE, align ="right")

  #Extract residuals from the models
  res = rollapply(df, width= k, FUN = function(x) 
    residuals(lm(r~t, data = as.data.frame(x))), by.column = FALSE, align ="right")

  #Standard deviation and Mean of residuals, on a row basis
  s = as.data.frame(apply(res, 1, sd))
  m = as.data.frame(apply(res, 1, mean)) #note that this is aproximately 0 due to detrending.  

  #Combine the data define n as number of rows in the dataset
  dataset = cbind(models, res, m, s)
  n = as.vector(nrow(dataset))
  n
  dataset

  #Compute predictions at k+1
  for(i in n){
    x = k + 1
    preds = dataset$`(Intercept)` + dataset$t*(x)
    x = x + 1
  }

  #Compute coefficient of variation
  for(j in n){
    n2 = k +1 
    tau = ((1 + 1 / (4*(n2))) * (dataset$apply.res..1..sd./dataset$apply.res..1..mean.))
  }

  dataset3 = cbind(dataset, tau)
  dataset3
  #Compute mean of chi distribution and the adjusted standard deviation
  Mchi <- sqrt(2)*((gamma((k+1)/2))/gamma(k/2))
  S = s*Mchi*(k+1)/sqrt(k)

  #Compute z7, checking whether the adjusted sd or cv should be used
  for(i in nrow(dataset3)){
    if (abs(dataset3$tau*dataset3$preds) < e) {
      z = -(dataset3$EA + dataset3$preds) / S
    } else 
      z = -(dataset3$EA + dataset3$preds) /(dataset3$tau*dataset3$preds)
  }
}
```

As is noticeable, I am creating a function that creates an adjusted standardised score. Typically, the Z-score is defined as (x - mean)/sd.

In this case, we are taking into account the fact that x is a random variable which is nonstationary. Therefore, the measure must be estimated on a rolling basis and constructed iteratively over the number of observations.

df is the dataset of interest, k is the window length used for estimating the rolling linear models, and e is simply a value used to test whether the adjusted standard deviation is too small to use the coefficient of variation rather than an alternative standard deviation that is adjusted for heteroscedasticity.

I am getting an error when I run my function with the following test measures:

```
t = seq(0,15,1)
r = (100+50*sin(0.8*t))
EA = rnorm(0:15)
df = data.frame(t,r,EA)

test = z7(df, 3, 0.00000000001)
```

The error is:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 14, 0
```

The traceback is:

```
5.
stop(gettextf("arguments imply differing number of rows: %s", 
    paste(unique(nrows), collapse = ", ")), domain = NA) 
4.
data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) 
3.
cbind(deparse.level, ...) 
2.
cbind(dataset, tau) 
1.
z7(df, 3, 1e-11)
```

How can I fix this error? Also, is there a way to simplify my code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error occurs at line

```
tau = ((1 + 1 / (4*(n2))) * (dataset$apply.res..1..sd./dataset$apply.res..1..mean.))
```

I changed it to

```
    tau = ((1 + 1 / (4*(n2))) * (dataset$`apply(res, 1, sd)`/dataset$`apply(res, 1, mean)`))
```

And in the last `for` loop I guess there is a problem with `dataset3$preds`

```
>dataset3$preds
NULL
```

And at the beginning you declared `r = df$ROA` but I think this sets `r` equal to `NULL`.

Hope that was useful!

Greetings

WW